# Make Windows 10 show password prompt immediately instead of requiring an action first

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

In Ubuntu, when a computer is locked, you can just type the password immediately followed by enter and it will unlock. This is nifty because I can type the password before the monitors have even turned back on.

I want to achieve this on my Windows 10 machine. The issue is that I seem to need to hit a key to wake Windows up, then another key to make it go from its relatively blank lock screen to the screen that actually shows the password. The time it takes to show the password prompt isn't instantaneous. The end result is that what I often end up doing is spamming spacebar a bit to get to where this prompt should be, then spam backspace in case I ended up typing into the password prompt, then enter my password. It fails a lot, presumably because I started typing my password too soon, anyway.

I want the lock screen to just show my password prompt from the start instead of this relatively blank and useless lock screen it starts off on.

Comment: It sounds weird, but disabling the lock screen while authentication is required, does exactly what you want. :)

Comment: Good find, LPChip. It is a duplicate. I couldn't find anything in my search earlier.